# How to read data from XNode

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I read data from XNode.

Here is my XNode I got from another query.

```
<claim kind="national" sequence="1">
  <country>UK</country>
  <number>66</number>
  <date>20080602</date>
</claim>
<claim kind="national" sequence="3">
  <country>TH</country>
  <number>61</number>
  <date>20090316</date>
</claim>
```

I want to get the country and date value.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try,

```
var list = from ele in XDocument.Load(@"c:\file.xml").Descendants("claim")
           select new
            {
              Country=(string)ele.Element("country"),
              Date=(string)ele.Element("date")
             };
 foreach (var t in list)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(t.Country + " "+ t.Date );
 }
```

EDIT:

```
string country=(string)((XElement)xNodeObj).Element("country");
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. How should I try since this xml is already in XNode (not from a file).

Comment: XDocument.Descendants is exactly what i was looking for to grab the nodes as XElements, cheers m8!  foreach (XElement node in XDocument.Parse(xmlString).Descendants("filter"))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using XPath:

```
string xml = "<main><claim kind=\"national\" sequence=\"1\"> <country>UK</country> <number>66</number>  <date>20080602</date></claim><claim kind=\"national\" sequence=\"3\">  <country>TH</country>  <number>61</number>  <date>20090316</date></claim></main>";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
doc.XPathSelectElement("//claim[country = 'TH']/number").Value.Dump("xpath stuff");
```